# Will this work if I change the active sheets throughout my code?

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I am running a script to format sheets in an existing excel file. Here is what I have now:

```
public void Main()
        {
            string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
            try
            {
                string FileName = Dts.Variables["User::DestinationFilePath1"].Value.ToString();
                string FolderName = Dts.Variables["User::DestinationFolder1"].Value.ToString();

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                xlApp.Visible = false;

                Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName);
                Sheets xlSheets = xlWorkbook.Worksheets;
                Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets[1];
                sheet.Select(Type.Missing);




                xlWorkbook.Save();
                xlWorkbook.Close(true);

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                // Create Log File for Errors
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::DestinationFilePath1"].Value.ToString()  + datetime + ".log"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

                }

             }
        }
```

It doesn't do anything at the moment, just opens the workbook and sets the active worksheet. There are 3 different sheets in the workbook that I need to format, so would I be able to do this like so?:

```
   try
            {
                string FileName = Dts.Variables["User::DestinationFilePath1"].Value.ToString();
                string FolderName = Dts.Variables["User::DestinationFolder1"].Value.ToString();

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                xlApp.Visible = false;

                Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName);
                Sheets xlSheets = xlWorkbook.Worksheets;


                Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets[1];
                sheet.Select(Type.Missing);

                     //do work here

                Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets[2];
                sheet.Select(Type.Missing);

                     //do work here

                Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets[3];
                sheet.Select(Type.Missing);

                     //do work here

                xlWorkbook.Save();
                xlWorkbook.Close(true);

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
```

Comment: Just try and find out!!

Comment: Does it look like it should work in theory though, or am I breaking some fundamental rules of the language?

Comment: This will only break if other sheets e.g. `xlApp.Worksheets[2]` doesn't exist in the excel. Add a check before accessing additional sheets.